# Is there any reason to carry a dead teammate?

Tags: xcom-2

If someone is killed during a mission, you still have the option to carry them around.  Is there any reason you might do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the mission involves extraction, and you do not carry their body to the extraction point and then extract while carrying them, you will lose whatever gear they have equipped.  It's also possible for people to be knocked unconscious and they likewise need to be carried to extraction.

Comment: As an example, if I have a scope on a weapon and I don't extract the body, that scope will be lost?

Comment: @Kyle W correct.  Weapons are not unique by themselves, but if you mod a weapon it essentially becomes so (if upgraded it retains the mods you used on it).  So if you fail to carry the body of someone using all default gear to extraction, you won't lose anything.  But if they have a modded weapon, it will be gone.

Comment: Also, you are a bad person if you willingly leave people behind.

Comment: @STT LCU no doubt :)

Comment: @STTLCU My soldiers may be bad people, but they're ALIVE bad people

Comment: Forget the upgraded weapons: if your dead/unconscious soldier is wearing upgraded tier 2 or tier 3 armor, you're not going to get that armor back if you leave them behind, so unless you happen to have a spare WAR suit back at the Avenger, you're going to have to build a new one, or fall back to using lower tier equipment. You also lose utility items on any soldiers left behind.